# Insert IFRAME in plain text into Textarea HTML tag

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have a trouble trying to insert an "iframe" in plain text into a "textarea" HTML tag, to be able to be taken and copied by the users of the app. I can't get that text:

```
<iframe id="ifr" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/'.$id_video.'?start='.$inicio.'&end= '.$fin.'"></iframe>
```

It contains some vars in order to start and end at defined times. I want to insert it into the next HTML tag:

```
<input type="textarea" id="area" rows="2" cols=""/>
```

And I tried doing the next sentence in JavaScript:

```
<script>

    var ifrElem = document.getElementById('ifr');
    var ifrContentWindow = ifrElem.contentWindow;

    var ifrDocBody = ifrContentWindow.document.body;
    var ifrInner = ifrDocBody.innerHTML;

    document.getElementById('area').value = ifrInner;

</script>
```

Any idea?
Thanks all!

Comment: You don't have access to cross domain iframe's, so you can't get the HTML from Youtube. It's called the same-origin policy, and javascript has one!

Comment: iframe inside textarea makes no sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `<textarea>...</textarea>` instead of the (non-existing) `<input type='textarea' value='...'/>`

You will find out that textareas don't need escaping. You can just do

```html
<textarea>
  <iframe src="..."></iframe>
</textarea>
```

and you will automatically see the text `<iframe src='...'></iframe>` inside your textarea.

Comment: escaping is required for Internet Explorer.

Comment: since @toni_piu is using PHP as evident from the first snippet, you're better off with `<?=html_special_chars('<iframe id="ifr" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/'.$id_video.'?start='.$inicio.'&end= '.$fin.'"></iframe>')?>` instead.

Comment: @HenryChan Which version(s) of IE are you talking about? IIRC, even IE doesn't need escaping.

Comment: I remember testing unescaped code in textarea in ie 7 or 8 before, and the contents spilled out……